# Once again PyQt newbie Pass current record from tableview to Qdialog / Mapper form in other class

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Qsqltable in tableview in a class (KL_browse)
The QsqlTable has a selectionbar and to edit the selected record i call a form in another class (Test_win)

How can i pass the selected record in the Tableview to the mapper in the form ???

See code example (test & play code !)

class Test_win(QDialog,ui_test_win.Ui_test_win):

def **init**(self, state, index):
        super(Test_win, self).**init**()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.state = state
        self.index = index

# Make some local modifications on the generated ui
        self.naam_edt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

# Set model

```
    self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
    self.model.setTable("KLANTEN")
    self.model.select()
```

# Set mappings fields to view
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper.ManualSubmit)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)

```
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.klnr_edt, 0)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.naam_edt, 1)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.straat_edt, 2)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.huisnr_edt, 3)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.gemeente_edt, 4)
```

# connections & slots
        self.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.save_Record)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.prev_Record)
   # set in Add mode
        if state == 0:
            query = QSqlQuery("""SELECT MAX(KLANTNR) as KLANTNR
                             FROM KLANTEN""")
            query.next()
            if query.isValid():
                Hklantnr =  query.value(0)
            else:
                return None
            self.klnr_edt.setText(str(Hklantnr + 1))
            row = self.model.rowCount()
            self.model.insertRow(row)
            self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
            self.naam_edt.setFocus()
   # set in Edit mode
            query = QSqlQuery("""SELECT * FROM KLANTEN WHERE KLANTNR = self.index """)
            query.next()

```
        self.naam_edt.setFocus()
```

def prev_Record(self):
        self.mapper.toNext()

def save_Record(self):

```
    self.mapper.submit()
    QDialog.done(self, True)
```

# Voor beeld van browse door klantenbestand

class KL_browse(QDialog, ui_kl_browse.Ui_kl_browse):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(KL_browse, self).__init__()
   # query = QSqlQuery()

   # query.exec_("""SELECT * FROM klanten ORDER BY klantnaam""")

    self.setupUi(self)

    self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
    self.model.setTable("KLANTEN")
    self.model.select()
    self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
    self.tableView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
    self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
 #   self.view.setColumnHidden(ID, True)
 #   index = self.tableView.model().index(0, 1)
 #   self.tableView.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(index, QItemSelectionModel.NoUpdate)      

    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(1,0)
    self.tableView.selectRow(0)
    self.tableView.selectColumn(1) 

    index = self.tableView.model().index(0, 1)
    self.tableView.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

# Volgende code is om de actie op knoppen en dergelijke op te vangen
        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_record)
        self.Del_button.clicked.connect(self.del_record)
        self.ed_button.clicked.connect(self.edt_record)

```
def del_record(self):
     index = self.tableView.currentIndex()
     self.model.removeRow(index.row())
     self.model.submitAll()
     self.model.select()
     index = self.tableView.model().index(0, 1)
     self.tableView.setCurrentIndex(index)


def add_record(self):
     self.test_win = Test_win(0) # 0 = add mode
     self.test_win.exec_() 
     self.model.select()
     index = self.tableView.model().index(0, 1)
     self.tableView.setCurrentIndex(index)

def  edt_record(self):
     index = self.tableView.currentIndex()   
     self.test_win = Test_win(1, index)  # 1 = Edit mode
     self.test_win.exec_() 
   #  self.model.select() 
   #  self.tableView.activateWindow()
```

Comment: The example code is longish and still not complete. A minimal running example would be better. And have you thought about communication with [signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)?

Answer (score 1):

this is a established control:

```
self.tableview.connect(self.tableview,SIGNAL('clicked(QModelIndex)'),
        lambda x:self.mapper.setCurrentModelIndex(self.tableview.selectedIndexes()[0]))

    def connects(self):
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.topPushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),lambda:self.arrow('firstRecord'))
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.lastPushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),lambda:self.arrow('lastRecord'))
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.beforePushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),lambda:self.arrow('prevRecord'))
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.nextPushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),lambda:self.arrow('nextRecord'))
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.newPushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.newRecord)
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.modifyPushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.modifyRecord)
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.deletePushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.deleteRecord)
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.savePushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.saveRecord)
        self.connect(self.controlButtons.cancelPushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.cancelRecord)


    def arrow(self, arrow):
        if arrow=='firstRecord':self.mapper.toFirst()
        elif arrow=='lastRecord':self.mapper.toLast()
        elif arrow=='prevRecord':self.mapper.toPrevious()
        elif arrow=='nextRecord':self.mapper.toNext()
        self.tableSelectRow()

    def tableSelectRow(self):
        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        if self.tableview:
            self.tableview.selectRow(row)

    def newRecord(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.arrow('lastRecord')

    def modifyRecord(self):pass

    def deleteRecord(self):
        if (QMessageBox.question(None,"Delete","Really Delete?",QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)==QMessageBox.No):
            return
        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.model.removeRow(row)
        self.model.submitAll()
        if row + 1 >= self.model.rowCount(): row-=1
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
        self.tableSelectRow()

    def saveRecord(self):
        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.mapper.submit()
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
        self.tableSelectRow()

    def cancelRecord(self): 
        self.mapper.revert()
        self.tableSelectRow()
```